# How to find out the arguments passed into a process and where the arguments are taken from?

Tags: linux, process, configuration, environment-variables, kubernetes

I'm trying to configure OpenShift (regardless whatever the application is), it starts the Kubelet with Hyperkube. It has a bunch of arguments passed into it, I can see that with the help of `ps -ef | grep hyperkube`.

`/usr/bin/hyperkube kubelet --v=2 --address=0.0.0.0 --allow-privileged=true --anonymous-auth=true --authentication-token-webhook=true --authentication-token-webhook-cache-ttl=5m --authorization-mode=Webhook --authorization-webhook-cache-authorized-ttl=5m --authorization-webhook-cache-unauthorized-ttl=5m so-on-and-on-and-on`.

Now how do I know where the arguments are taken from? I checked the environment variables, I don't see them. It is reading it from some config file, is it possible to find out what that file is?

Answer (score 1):

The two resources I have found indicate towards config files that pass on the arguments. The following link provides an example of how to make a config file and subsequently there is a link to how to edit the configurations:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/
The following article goes in to great length about configuration settings and some of the ones that were being passed as arguments for you can be found in this article:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/x-team.com/blog/introduction-kubernetes-architecture/amp/